Issues with WPGraphQL Smart Cache Integration in Next.js 14 with Apollo Client
I’m having trouble integrating WPGraphQL Smart Cache with my Next.js 14 application using Apollo Client. The integration isn’t working as expected, and I’m not seeing the x-cache header in my responses.
Setup:
Next.js Version: 14
WordPress Hosting: DigitalOcean droplet
GraphQL Plugin: WPGraphQL Smart Cache
Apollo Client: Configured to use cache-first fetch policy
GraphQL Query Example: Fetching companySubmissions
Current Code:
here is my wordpress configuration:


**Apollo Client Configuration (lib/apollo.js):
**
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const link = ApolloLink.from([
  new HttpLink({
    uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_API_URL}/graphql`,
    useGETForQueries: true,
  }),
]);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    },
  },
});

Data Fetching Function (graphql/resolvers/company.resolver.js):
export const usePartners = async () => {
  try {
    const { data, errors } = await client.query({
      query: getCompanies,
      fetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    });

    if (errors) {
      console.error('GraphQL errors:', errors);
      return { errors };
    }

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch partners:', error);
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch partners: ${error.message}`);
  }
};

Component (app/partners/page.js):
import Partners from "@/components/partners";
import Image from "next/image";
import PartnerBanner from "@/assets/images/partnerBanner.png";
import LineHeader from "@/components/lineHeader";
import { usePartners } from "@/graphql/resolvers/company.resolver";

export default async function PartnersPage() {
  const { companySubmissions } = await usePartners();
  
  return (
    <div className="w-full 2xl:pt-48 md:pt-36 pt-28 px-6 py-5 2xl:max-w-[107rem] max-w-[80rem]">
             <h3>hello world </h3>
    </div>
  );
}



The WPGRaphQL Smart Cache does not add the x-cache header itself. That header is added by the cache. As the docs mention the "Network Cache" requires a supported integration. WP Engine is currently the only host I'm aware of that supports this out of the box, though Jason Bahl has provided some examples for integration with Varnish and Litespeed
As you can see from a basic local install there is no x-cache header:
headers from a GraphQL request
However, on my site that is on WP Engine hosting those x-cache headers are provided cause that is the cache (Cloudflare) noting that it is returning a cached response.
headers for GraphQL request on a WP Engine site
There is another option; while it won't enable the x-cache header, it will enable some caching. You may opt to enable the Object-Cache caching. That said, this is not an ideal situation, and Network Caching is highly recommended. The Object Cache will not add x-cache headers but you can see the fact it's working in the GraphQL response:
graphql response with object cache enabled
